# Why am I getting free(): invalid pointer?

Tags: c, posix

I am currently reading Linux System Programming by Robert Love and am stuck on the read() example that takes care of all five error cases. I am getting an `free(): invalid pointer` error. I am assuming that it has something to do with advancing the buffer in case the read is not finished.

It works if I store the offset and return the pointer to its original position. This is not mentioned in the book. Is there a better approach?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int fd;

    if( (fd = open("someFile.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0664)) < 0)
        perror("open for write");

    char * text =  "This is an example text";
    write(fd, text, strlen(text));

    close(fd);

    if( (fd = open("someFile.txt", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        perror("open");

    char *buf; 

    if( (buf = (char *) calloc(50, sizeof(char))) == NULL )
        perror("calloc");

    int len = 50;
    ssize_t ret;

    /* If I store the offset in a variable it works */

    off_t offset = 0;

    while (len != 0 && (ret = read (fd, buf, len)) != 0) {
        if (ret == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            perror ("read");
            break;
        }

        len -= ret;
        buf += ret;
        offset += ret;  // Offset stored here

    }

    if( close(fd) == -1 )
        perror("close");

    buf -= offset;     // Here I return the pointer to its original position
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm, what's the actual error you get exactly?

Comment: And also, "It works if I store the offset and return the pointer to its original position." Isn't that exactly what the code does? So is this the code that doesn't work, or one that does? I'm not sure if I can tell. If it's one that does work, then it would probably help to see the one that does _not_ work, to be able to see where the problem is.

Comment: I am getting ``free(): invalid pointer`` as mentioned above. I found a fix by storing the offset and reverting the buf pointer to its original position, shortly after posting. There is probably a better way.

Comment: You read up to 50 (`len`) bytes into `buf` which was allocated a size of 20. Memory corruption ensues. (Probably you actually read 22 bytes, since that's the length of `text` if I counted correctly).

Comment: Good spotting... I missed the 50/20.  That should be in a variable or constant and the same one used in both places.

Comment: @PaulHankin Have you tried your solution? It doesn't work. I corrected the value and it still has the same issue.

Comment: Right, I guess the original is revision 1 here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/668570/revisions

Comment: I didn't give a solution, I said that you read up to 50 bytes (most likely 22 bytes) into a buffer of size 20, and that memory corruption follows.

Comment: That was just a typo actually. I had that fixed in my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in this code.

First, `perror` is not being used correctly, as it only prints an error -- there should also be code here to abort on errors, so subsequent code doesn't try to use results from operations that failed.

Secondly, only the result from `calloc` can be given to free.  The result is saved in `buf`, but then later code changes the value of `buf` and tries to free the changed value.  Storing the changes in `offset` should fix this, but this is an error prone solution at best.  If you have multiple code paths that modify `buf`, you have to make sure every one of those also modify offset in the same way.

A better approach would be to not modify `buf`, and instead use a second pointer variable in the read that is initialized to the value of `buf` and then gets modified after each read.

As pointed out, the number given to `calloc` is different than the number `len` is initialized to.  This is a perfect example of misuse of a magic number.  Both the 20 and 50 should be replaced with the same symbol (variable or constant or #define) so that you don't get a buffer overrun error.

Comment: Can you provide a better example? I use perror to check for errors. I return from the function when necessary. That is not really relevant for this code snippet. I made the buffer to store the data, so I wouldn't know what else to store it in. I already tried making a copy of the pointer, but that didn't work.

Comment: Ah well it works if I make a copy and only modify the copy. You are right. What I tried was the other way round.

Comment: You have fixed a symptom by using a copy, but really the problem is the buffer overrun.  See my comment below your question.

Comment: A better pattern for perror would be  `if (checkerror) { perror(...); exit(1); }`  Or in C++, throw an exception.

Comment: @user10489 I don't want my program to exit.

Comment: @neolith, well, if the first `open()` fails, `fd` will be set to -1, and calling `read()` and `close()` on that will also just return errors since that's definitely an invalid fd. If the `calloc()` fails, `buf` will be `NULL` and the following `read()` will get that null pointer which I guess will be undefined behaviour, but in practice will probably just crash the program. In the first one, you could of course you could wrap the writes within the conditional, and continue with the reading part, but in the reading part there's just no way to continue if you don't have the buffer to read to.

Comment: Would you rather have your program crash and exit, or exit cleanly or just produce wrong results?   You need to do some kind of error handling after the perror, and `exit` (or `return`) is the simplest.

Comment: If the open for write fails, then fd is invalid, and all subsequent code that uses fd will fail.  What is the correct action here?  Exiting would work.  Adding code elsewhere to not use fd would work but is probably silly.  Retrying the open might work -- but what if that fails too?  Just exiting with an error is probably best.

Comment: @user10489 I would rather like to handle those errors appropriately. The program must not crash or exit. Errors can also occur when the implementation is correct. In that case the program should just continue. Rather deallocate, close everything and return the function with -1.

Comment: The program will always exit unless you have an infinite loop in it.  The question is, what should it do when operations fail.  At the least, it should skip all subsequent code that rely on those operations doing something useful.  At best, it should tell the user it failed and abort, allowing the user to take corrective action and retry.  In between actions are more complicated.

Comment: Yeah that sounds better. I am pretty happy that the program is not crashing anymore atm. I will improve it over time.